# Modify a component class variable from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a variable inside my `Hue` class  in a component :

```
export default class Hue extends Component {


  state = {
    toggleState : false,
    toggleWhite : false
  }


      render(){...}
...
}
```

Inside this component I am able to modify a value like this : `this.state.toggleState = true`

I have another component which handles websocket connections, when I receive data I want to modify the data inside the `Hue` class. But I am unable, even if I import `Hue` in my websocket component, to modify the value.

I've been tried : `Hue.state.toggleState = true` but this is undefined.

How can I access and modify a value from another component or is there any alternative solutions for this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: 2 ways: take the toggleState as a property and have the web socket set that property when rending hue or have shared state, if using redux they would essentially get state from the same reducer.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but, never change your state directly (i.e. `this.state.toggleState = true`). Doing it that way will not trigger the `componentDidUpdate` and therefore it will not re-render. The correct way is by calling `this.setState({ toggleState: true })`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly.

Comment: How can I do this @floor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Hue component is parent to the websocket component, you could pass your websocket component a function to run when data is updated.

```
        <WebSocketHandlingComponent
          onUpdate={latestData => {
            this.setState({toggleState: latestData.toggleState});
          }}
        />
```

It isn't clear if that is how you have your app structured though. If you have multiple components at different levels of the tree needing access to the same data then you probably need a proper state management solution such as `redux`

Comment: It works but every time I trigger the setState function (using `this.props.onUpdate(myvalue)`, it is triggered twice, like 2 times then 4 times, then 8..16..32 etc. How can I limit to one trigger ?

Comment: Nervermind, it was related to the fact that it was triggered out of my authentification socket function. Leading to two time execution each time.